# regex c# ip adress

Tags: c#

почему проверка не работает? Правильно ли я понимаю что [0-255] означает любое число от 0 до 255?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на картинке не совсем видно, я ввожу 6.7.7.8

Comment: Нет, неправильно, вам нужно прочитать [документацию по синтаксису регулярных выражений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). Квадратные скобки задают **один символ**, и вы в них прописали, что это может быть символ между 0 и 2 или 5 (то есть допустимы символы 0, 1, 2, 5). Кроме того, точка обозначает **любой символ**, то есть ваш код будет считать ввод `5q0w2e1` корректным

Comment: код надо вставлять текстом и есть готовый метод `IPAddress.Parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вы используете неправильный синтаксис Regex**, я нашёл нормальный Regex под IPv4 -

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^((1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|\d\d?)\.?){4}$");
```

Для проверки использовал:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^((1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|\d\d?)\.?){4}$");
string text1 = "128.0.0.1";
string text2 = "256.0.0.1";
string text3 = "0.0.0.0";
string text4 = "255.255.255.255";
string text5 = "255:228:0:0";
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(text1)); //True
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(text2)); //False
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(text3)); //True
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(text4)); //True
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(text5)); //False
```

Comment: Если максимально придираться — ipv4 адрес `2539995461` является корректным (можете проверить, замечательно пингуется), но эта регулярка считает его некорректным. И наоборот — адрес `233233233233` является некорректным, но регулярка считает его корректным

Comment: @andreymal, можете скинуть через разделение .?

Comment: Первый просто попингуйте, ping сам его покажет. Второй некорректный, его показать невозможно

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse